# Is it possible to stop a JavaScript redirect in a browser?

Tags: java, javascript, redirect, browser

Oracle has added some obnoxious Javascript that redirects to a JRE download page if you visit the [JApplet tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) and you don't have the desired (latest) version of the plugin installed OR you're using a browser that doesn't support it, like Chrome 32-bit.  So you cannot even view the tutorial!  (The most charitable explanation is that this is an oversight.)

I know I can grab this page using `curl` for example.  But how can I stop this redirect from happening in a browser?

Here is the offending JS:  https://gist.github.com/8e8df15b2238c2171fed.git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All good browsers have an option to disable JavaScript.

In Chrome, for example:

More tools > Developers tools > Settings > Disable JavaScript.

Comment: Doh, of course.  Also effective, `Settings > Advanced > Privacy > Content Settings > JavaScript > Manage Exceptions` to disable for this one page.